# What operations might I might perform on a file that would cause the file.lastModified() call to change it's value?

Tags: java, file

I'm wondering what types of programmatic behaviors count as "modifying" a file in java.  That is, what operations which i might perform on a file would cause the file.lastModified() call to change it's value?

I.E.  Opening? Reading? Writing? Copying?   Writing is an obvious trigger, but the others aren't so obvious.  I've done some looking around online and not seen anything immediate.

Clarification:  I'm not tyring to set the last modified time, i'm just attempting to determine what programmatic behaviors which a java program might engage in would cause this value to update.  Obviously writing to a file would do this.  But are there other cases which do cause this?

Comment: The "Last Modified" flag is a function of the operating system; java just passes this value to you.  Anything that would change a single byte in the file should change the "Last Modified" date; so would a [touch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_(Unix)).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I understand that the flag is an OS function.  I'm trying to chase down what might cause this flag to update from my program.

Comment: Rather than us speculating on what might be the cause, your time might be better spent tracking down the point in your code at which the LastModified change gets triggered.

Comment: I appreciate that, but I was hoping there might be a list somewhere which lists the operations.

Comment: Opening a file and reading it isn't modifying it. Writing to it is modifying it. You don't need a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading depends on opening, Copying depends on reading. Writing is the only trigger to set the Last Modified stamp. Once you open a file, in most operating systems, you need to specify what modes you want to open the file with. e.g. `rw` or `r` or `w` or `a` (append) etc. (implementation / os dependant). Since `a` includes `w`, `w` is the only operation that will set the Last Modified stamp.

Java classes (such as `FileInputStream`) will open the file specifying `r` or "read" - so that won't trigger the LastModified stamp. Java has distinct classes for Readers and Writers - Input and Output. The input/reader classes (`Reader`, `InputStream`) will not set the LastModified stamp. However, a simple Open-For-Write (without actually writing) will most likely also trigger the LastModified stamp, i.e.:

```
new FileOutputStream( new File( "path/to/file.extension" ) );
```

will most likely trigger the LastModified set.

Regards.

Comment: It's not really correct to say it will trigger a lastModified change. It will create an entire new file with a new creation date, as well as a new last-modified date.